# error: method onCreate(Bundle) is already defined in class MainActivity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout

I'm pretty new to android development. I'm aware I shouldn't use duplicate `onCreate()`, but I don't know how to do this than. I'm creating two spinners from sqlite database on the same layout.

My code is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Create DataHelper object and insert some sample data
        DataHelper datahelper = new DataHelper(this);

        datahelper.insertBreed ("Beagle");
        datahelper.insertBreed ("Bulldog");
        datahelper.insertBreed ("Chow Chow");

        // Get sample data from the database and display them in the spinner
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerBreeds);
        ArrayList<String> list = datahelper.getAllBreeds();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.text, list);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Create DataHelper object and insert some sample data
        DataHelper2 datahelper2 = new DataHelper2(this);

        datahelper2.insertAge("1");
        datahelper2.insertAge ("2");
        datahelper2.insertAge("3");

        // Get sample data from the database and display them in the spinner
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAge);
        ArrayList<String> list = datahelper2.getAllAge();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.text, list);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: You just put it all in one method and give the variables different names (i.e. `spinner2`). Though I'd use more descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** have 2 override of same method inside your class.

Just copy the code that initialize these 2 spinners from second `onCreate()` to the first one. Change variable name of spinner and adapter to **avoid duplicate**. (Ex: `spinner` -> `spinnerBreeds`/`spinnerAge`, `datahelper` -> `breedsDataHelper`/`ageDataHelper`, `adapter` -> `breedsAdapter`/`ageAdapter`)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create DataHelper object and insert some sample data
    DataHelper datahelper = new DataHelper(this);
    datahelper.insertBreed ("Beagle");
    datahelper.insertBreed ("Bulldog");
    datahelper.insertBreed ("Chow Chow");

    // Get sample data from the database and display them in the spinner
    Spinner spinnerBreeds= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerBreeds);
    ArrayList<String> list = datahelper.getAllBreeds();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.text, list);
    spinnerBreeds.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Init second spinner
    DataHelper2 datahelper2 = new DataHelper2(this);
    datahelper2.insertAge("1");
    datahelper2.insertAge ("2");
    datahelper2.insertAge("3");

    // Get sample data from the database and display them in the spinner
    Spinner spinnerAge = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAge);
    ArrayList<String> list2 = datahelper2.getAllAge();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.text, list2);
    spinnerAge.setAdapter(adapter2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very usefull, i also fixed the last line into spinnerAge.setAdapter ... but now spinners on device are both the same. Second one appears like the first one

Comment: Same about UI or data?

Comment: data, you can choose between breeds

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forget to change list -> list2 when creating adapter2.
`ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.text, list2);`

Answer (score 0):

You have two methods

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

in your code, and that is why you get the error.

You should remove one of them and put the code into the other method.